# Find the equation of the tangent line to the graph of g'(x) = 2

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, tangent-line

Find the equation of the tangent line to the graph of: $$g(x) = 3x^8+2x^2+5x$$ at the point where $g'(x)=2$.

The choices provided for a multiple choice question on a student's high school calculus homework do not seem to match my attempts:

- $y=3.799x-0.180$
- $y=3.799x+0.180$
- $y=6.201x-0.180$
- $y=6.201x$

The answer I got was $y = 2x - 1.02983$.

Comment: If g'(x) = 2 then the slope of the tangent line would be 2; do you mean the point where g(x) = 2?

Comment: Even assuming the question was meant to be "at the point where g(x) = 2" (which would be near x = 0.351 by my graphing calculator), none of these options are correct, because the slope there would be approx. 6.419, and not 6.201

Comment: In case $g'(x)=2$ the slope of the tangent should be $2$.

Comment: @RobBland After spending more time on the question, I agree the question is written wrong. Correct me if I'm wrong, but if g'(x) = 2, then the equation of the tangent line should be y = 2x - 1.02983. And I tried duplicating your result for 6.419 if g(x) = 2, but was not able to. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelHoppe If it was a typo and suppose to be g(x)=2, what would the equation be then?

Comment: tangent line is g'(x)=24x^7+ 4x+5. We don't usually find tangent lines for y values, though.

Comment: @scribbles In that case also none of the given solution is the right one.